# Unable to open the cshtml page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have developed an application and deployed to cloud. By default index page is loading but once index page is loaded on click on it it will open other page(cshtml page). But i am getting blank page . Please help

```
    Index.cshtml code

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>Create Invoice Online for Free & Download PDF</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/bootstrap.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/quick-invoice.css" />

            <script type="text/javascript" src="../Content/jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../Content/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <meta name="google-site-verification" content="FB0t_l2pYlfmLe1hzPyjLXXhDF8Bufut_nDhCP5brrQ" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="brand" href="/">Invoices generator</a>
                        <div class="nav-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="/"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i>Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/CreateInvoices/Create"><i class="icon-file icon-white"></i> Invoice Templates</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container layout">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span9">
                        <div class="container-narrow">
                            <div class="container-narrow jumbotron">
                                <h1>Shopping Cart Online Invoice Generator</h1>

                                <p class="lead">Create &amp; Send your invoice without having to register, and download as <strong>PDF, </strong>quickly &amp; easily for free, email your invoice &nbsp;Select an invoice template from our invoices templates list, Save or send your invoice in minutes</p>

                                <hr />      <a href="/CreateInvoices/Create" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Create your invoice</a>
                                <hr />

                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="pop-layouts">
                            <h4>Invoice Templates</h4>
                            <ul class="thumbnails">
                                <li>
                                    <h4>Shopping Cart Invoice Template</h4>
                                    <a class="thumbnail" href="create" title="Shopping Cart Invoice Template">
                                        <img src="../Images/057e7_b4a13_1.jpg" alt="" date-large="../Images/4dad1_733d6_1.png" />
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="caption">
                                        <!--<a href="/templates/preview/1" class="btn btn-info" target="_blank"><i class="icon-eye-open icon-white"></i> Preview</a>-->
                                        <a href="/CreateInvoices/Create" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i> Create</a>
                                    </div>

                                </li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
                    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
                    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
                              m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
                })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

                ga('shopping-cart-invoices', 'UA-47492117-1', 'mybluemix.net');
                ga('send', 'pageview');



            </script>

        </body>
    </html>

Startup.cs

using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles;

public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        });

        app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
        {
            EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false,
        });

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(context.Request.Path);
            try
            {
                await next();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
        );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "CreateInvoice",
                template: "{controller=CreateInvoice}/{action=Create}/{id?}"
         );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Preview",
                template: "{controller=Preview}/{action=preview}/{id?}"
         );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Thanks",
                template: "{controller=Thanks}/{action=Thankyou}/{id?}");
        });

    }
}
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


}
```

Comment: on clicking on index? where and to which page u want to go

Comment: Createinvoice/Create.cshtml page

Comment: where is the controller and .cshtml file for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using

```
@Html.actionlink("Create", "CreateInvoice")
```

This will allow you to declare the action and the controller

It also means that you will get build errors if the action or controller do not exist

Comment: Can you suggest me where should i edit this in my code

Comment: You can replace this <a href="/CreateInvoices/Create">

With @Html.actionlink("Create", "CreateInvoices")

Comment: If you are aware can you please provide some links for Invoice application code

Comment: As in to create invoices ?